# App that prints everything after the last occurrence of :: in a string ( C )

Tags: c, while-loop, count, switch-statement, printf

I'm trying to write an app that prints everything after the last occurrence of 2 colons "::", so if it's 3 ":::" it won't count. if the string is "He::ll::o" it should print out "o" and if it's "12312::233" it should print out "233", I have to use `char* extract(char* input);` and a Pointer function `void extract2(char* input, char** output)` I just started learning `C` today and I'm a bit overwhelmed. I'm also not allowed to import libraries. this is what I have so far. any help is appreciated.

```
int isCH(char c) {
  return (c != ':' && c != '\0');
}

char *extract(char *input){
    int state = 1;
    char *doubleColon;
    
    while(1){
        switch(state){
            case 1:
                if(isCH(*input))
                state = 1;
                if(*input == '\0')
                state = 2;
                if(*input == ':') // first colon
                state = 3;
            break;
            case 2:
                return doubleColon;
            break;
            case 3:
                if(isCH(*input))
                state = 1;
                if(*input == '\0')
                state = 2;
                if(*input == ':'){ // second colon
                state = 4;
                doubleColon = input;
                }
            break;
            case 4:
                if(isCH(*input))
                state = 1;
                if(*input == '\0')
                state = 2;
                if(*input == ':')
                state = 1;
                break;
        }
        input++;
    }
}

int main() {
    printf("End of String: %c", *extract("Ha::ll::o"));
}
```

Comment: `extract` is not `return`ing anything and your `printf` call should use the `%s` format specifier.

Comment: Just a style note, it'll look better if you create an enum for your states so they have a name instead of a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach would be to go the end of the string and work toward the beginning. Then when the first pair of colons are located, the function can return.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *extract(char *input){
    char *doubleColon = NULL;
    char *end = input;
    int span = 0;

    //advence to end of string
    while ( *end) {
        ++end;
    }

    while ( end > input){
        --end;//work toward start of string
        if ( ':' == *end) {//found a colon
            doubleColon = end + 1;//set pointer
            span = 0;
            while ( ':' == *end) {//count consecutive colons
                ++span;
                if ( end == input && 2 == span) {
                    return doubleColon;
                }
                 if ( end == input) {
                    return NULL;
                }
               --end;
            }
            if ( 2 == span) {//two consecutive colons
                return doubleColon;
            }
            doubleColon = NULL;//reset pointer
        }
    }
    return doubleColon;
}

int main ( void) {
    printf ( "End of String: %s\n", extract ( "::Ha:::::ll:::o"));
    printf ( "End of String: %s\n", extract ( "::Ha::ll:::o"));
    printf ( "End of String: %s\n", extract ( "::Ha::ll::o"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit more universal function. It will return pointer to remaining chars after last occurence of any delimiter.

```
char *extract(char *input, const char *del)
{
    char *last = NULL, *current = NULL;
    size_t delLength = strlen(del);

    if(input && del && *del)
    {
        do
        {
            if(current)
            {
                last = current + delLength;
                input = last;
            }
        }while((current = strstr(input, del)));
    }
    return last;
}

int main() {
    char *res;
    printf("End of String: %s\n", (res = extract("Ha::ll::o", "::")) ? res : "Not found");
    printf("End of String: %s\n", (res = extract("Ha::ll::o", ":ll:")) ? res : "Not found");
    printf("End of String: %s\n", (res = extract("", "::")) ? res : "Not found");
    printf("End of String: %s\n", (res = extract(NULL, "::")) ? res : "Not found");
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/EbM1cP

Answer (score 0):

change these two lines

1. `doubleColon = input;` to `doubleColon = input+1;`
2. `printf("End of String: %c", *extract("Ha::ll::o"));` to `printf("End of String: %s", extract("Ha::ll::o"));`

Also check for the case if no `::` is present in input

```
char *str = NULL;// in main function you have to do this.
if(str = extract("Ha::ll::o"))
    printf("End of String: %s", str);
else
    printf("No :: present");
```

Comment: `extract` doesn't `return` anything.

Comment: `case 2` returns

Comment: I missed that.  It's bad practice to not have a `return` in every case or at the end, though.

Comment: why did I add the +1 to input? in doubleColon = input+1;

Comment: I say we need to add it. did you check the output without adding? you will get a `:` in output without it.

Comment: haven't noticed it at first, thanks! 

now I'm getting an error when I'm trying to use the if-else statement, it reads:

`main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:50:4: error: ‘str’ undeclared (first use in this function)
 if(str = extract("Ha::ll::o"))
    ^~~
main.c:50:4: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in`

Comment: you need to declare it, since it is not present in your original code. updated my above answer, please refer it.